# Deleting entry with the highest value from a table

Tags: sql

- `PLAYER` (playerId, playerName)
- `LEVEL` (levelId, levelName)
- `GAME` (playerId, levelId, time)

I want to delete the player having the highest time on levelId=1

I tried

```
DELETE FROM PLAYER
WHERE playerId = SELECT playerId 
                 FROM Game G
                 WHERE G.levelId = 1
                 AND G.time >= ALL(SELECT time FROM GAME 
                                   WHERE G.levelId = levelId);
```

This solution .. is it right?
Is there a better one?

Comment: MySQL and Oracle 10G are two very different databases.

Comment: Please be more specific what "better" is. Faster ? Less lines ?

Comment: is there a faster one ? @Marged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mean you want to delete any player so this will implies

```
DELETE FROM PLAYER WHERE playerId = any( SELECT playerId FROM Game G
WHERE G.levelId=1
AND
G.time>=ALL(SELECT time FROM GAME WHERE G.levelId=levelId));
```